# Run docker-compose from bash script file

Tags: shell, nginx, docker, scripting, containers

I am new to scripting and require some assistance. I am building docker container using YML file. I have YML code written to automate my web server (docker-compose.yml) and database server(docker-compose-mongo.yml).

Now I want to build a bash script that will call for both the yml files and run together.

I was wondering what commands do I need to type within my shell script to call for these two yml files and run them together. I initially just used

```
#!/bin/bash
run docker-compose.yml
```

But the above code didn't work.

Ps. below is my yml file for the web server

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.2"
          memory: 330M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    # networks:
      # - webnet
# networks:
  # webnet:
```

Comment: "from YML file" means just as much as "from JSON file" -- both are completely generic formats. The fact that it's a docker-compose description is *far* more relevant.

Comment: More to the point -- "didn't work" doesn't tell us *nearly* enough to be useful. At bare minimum, we'd want to know the exact error in question.

Comment: So the name of my script is test. sh and when i run my test script it gives an error " test.sh not found"

Comment: Nothing you're showing us here demonstrates how that script would be installed into the Docker container, and without that installation taking place, a failure is entirely consistent with what one would expect. Please try to include everything needed to reproduce the *exact error* as part of the question itself, and otherwise to comply with the [mcve] definition.

Comment: If you want to run docker-compose up statement, you just  run it. Remove the `run` command which is before the `docker-compose.yml` And you need to write `docker-compose up` to execute the compose process.

Comment: Your question title `Run a bash script from YML file` and your second paragraph `bash script that will call for both the yml` seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @Ayushya I've fixed the title

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call them separately:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose-mongo.yml up -d
```

Or combine both `nginx` and `mongo` services in the same `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: this doesn't work for me somehow.... It only runs the last docker compose. I am also changing directory can that be the reason?

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple yml files on the same command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-mongo.yml up -d
```